# Why/When would one study Renormalization Group flow of a system?

Tags: condensed-matter, renormalization, scaling

It is not that I am looking for a cheap way out of reading a book about RG flow, but I would like to know few key insights that RG flow study provides, backed with some specific examples. I know a little about scaling and concept of renormalization.

So, to be specific, if I have a system in hand, how will I know that using RG flow (correct me if I'm using it all wrong) will give me some deeper insight?